# Function to check the checkbox automatically in Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to do something for my project. Here I have some checkboxes. Now I want to check the first checkbox when I click on the start button. Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
text = []
var = []
for i in range(0,x):
    text.append("Process" + str( i + 1))


root = Tk()    
for i in range(0,x):
    var.append(IntVar())

def run():
    var[0] = IntVar(value = 1)

button = Button(root, text = "Run", command = run)
button.pack()

for i in range(0,x):
    l = Checkbutton(root, text=text[i], variable = var[i])
    l.pack(anchor = 'w')

root.mainloop()
```

But if I click on the start button, the checkbox is not getting checked.

Comment: `var[0].set(1)`, look for more explanation in the below comment by @TheLizzard, also don't import everything (don't use `*` when importing) and I suggest that you follow PEP 8 which states that there shouldn't be space around `=` operator when it is used for kwargs such as here: `variable = var[i]`, should be `variable=var[i]` however for assignments there should be space around such as you already do here for example: `l = Checkbutton...` (not mandatory but I strongly recommend, especially the thing about imports)

Comment: `var[0] = IntVar(value=1)` creates a new `IntVar` variable that isn't linked to anything. That is why you have to just set the old variable with the new value like what @Matiiss suggested